# Google and Typekit web fonts not loading in Firefox

Tags: firefox, webfonts, google-webfonts, typekit

I've been having a weird web fonts related problem with **Firefox only**.

To put it short, web fonts are not loading at all from Google or Typekit. This is also the case if I just browse to http://www.google.com/fonts or https://typekit.com/fonts

Here's how Firefox behaves on both sites:

[image: Google web fonts (above), Typekit (below)]

I checked [Typekit help](http://help.typekit.com/customer/portal/articles/807568#firefox) regarding this type of issue. All the mentioned settings were correct. Also removed and re-installed Firefox. Tried to connect through 3 different network connections. Nothing seem to help.

I'm sure it's some very basic Firefox setting or problem, but I just can't figure out what. Anyone had similar issues? Any solutions?

Windows 7 Enterprise (32-bit), Firefox 34.0.5.

No problems with latest Chrome, IE 11 or latest Safari.

Answer (score 0):

This is issue of Google web fonts not rendered

i think Mozilla support will help you, there is same issue and it solution also visite [mozilla support forum](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/958143)

This is bug that can be [found here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=857922)